# Finding matching pairs of round brackets given as a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples which looks like this:

```
[(' ( ', 0),
 (' ) ', 4),
 (' ( ', 5),
 (' ( ', 6),
 (' ) ', 10),
 (' ) ', 11)]
```

I need to get the list which will look like this one:

```
[(​ 0 ​ , ​ 4 ​ ), (​ 5 ​ , ​ 11​ ), (​ 6 ​ , ​ 10​ )]
```

The main task is find all pairs of round brackets (parentheses) in a given list of tuples.
string.

Comment: Will the tuples in the output always have 2 elements?

Comment: And why not `[(​ 0 ​ , ​ 11 ​ ), (​ 5 ​ , ​ 4 ), (​ 6 ​ , ​ 10​ )]` ?

Comment: Hi, would you please tell us what you've tried so far ?

Comment: it should be [(0,4), (5,10), (6,11)]. You are pairing numbers with ( and another number with ).

Comment: tuples always have 2 elements ( type_of_parentheses, number). You can see that first element of a list (' ( ', 0 )  the second  (' ) ', 4 )  - the first elements of this 2 tuples forms the pair  ( ), so I need to I must have (0,4)

Comment: That logic doesn't make sense since 5 and 6 are consecutive elements, and they dont form a pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the idiomatic way to pair brackets is by using a stack data structure.

whenever you see an opening bracket you push the value on the stack, whenever you see a closing bracket you pop a value from the stack to match it:

```py
brackets = [(' ( ', 0), (' ) ', 4), (' ( ', 5), (' ( ', 6), (' ) ', 10), (' ) ', 11)]

stack = []
solution = []
for bracket, num in brackets:
    if '(' in bracket:
        stack.append((bracket, num))
    elif ')' in bracket:
        solution.append((stack.pop()[1], num))

print(solution)
```

this works due to the **LIFO** (Last In First Out) nature of both stacks, and brackets.

meaning - a closing bracket should close the **Last** opening bracket encountered.

Comment: The order of the output is different from the desired order. Does that matter?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh good question, maybe it needs to be sorted by opening bracket. will ask.

Comment: Thanks this is working:)

Comment: @qwew does the order of output matter? does it need to be sorted by the first number?

Comment: @qwew anyways, if you need to sort it to match your original output, just use `solution.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])` after the `for` loop.